# Rabbitmq queue is always blocked after running for a while (using Docker )

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

In normal conditions,everything is right,but when we put our service in the docker,
it is always blocked after running for a while ,I wonder if there is something different configuration when using docker?or Could you give me a clue to solver this problems?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html
By default, when the RabbitMQ server uses above 40% of the available RAM, it raises a memory alarm and blocks all connections that are publishing messages
You can try setting more rabbitmq memory limit inside docker by command:

```
docker exec <your_container_id> rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.8
```

Or increase memory limit (cgroup) for your docker instance if memory limit is set too low

Comment: Thank your for your answer.But we don't deploy rabbitmq-server in docker. only our consumer-service is on docker. what's more , we checked out   the available RAM RabbitMQ using ,which is blow 40%, so maybe my questions is different from what your descritption. Is there another situation which can cause the queue blocked? (zero consumer in work)

Comment: which docker environment you are using? Just docker run command or docker orchestration tool